# Django Admin Emails

Tags: python, django, email

I've recently put my Django website into production, and I've turned debug off. I've also configured the `ADMINS` setting so that I can be informed of any errors occurring.

In my settings.py, I have the following:

`ADMINS = (('Foo', 'bar@example.com'))`

I use Zoho to send out emails. When I noticed I wasn't receiving anything, I checked the "Sent" folder on their site. It's trying to send an email to `<r>, <n>`

Why isn't my name and email being parsed, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ADMINS` should be a list of tuples.  You forgot to add a comma to make a list:

```
ADMINS = (('Foo', 'bar@example.com'), )
```

Or you cat use the `list` syntax:

```
ADMINS = [('Foo', 'bar@example.com')]
```